# Vimeo Player SDK - 'playing' event firing prematurely?

Tags: api, video, sdk, embed, vimeo

I'm having an issue where I'm using Vimeo Player SDK in a project and I don't want the user to see the thumbnail before playback. I'm triggering playback via code and attempting to display the video once it actually starts playing. I'm listening to the 'playing' event and would expect it to only trigger, once the video is actually playing. But I'm still getting the thumbnail. Am I missing something here?

For clarity, I'm listening to the `player.on('playing', ..)` event, not `player.on('play', ..)`

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/avt_pj/hqgtram0/31/

Answer (score 0):

Vimeo replied with this:

> The [`playing` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/playing_event) is fired by the `<video>` element itself, so
> we don't control the timing of that in our player.
>
> If it's critical to know the precise moment when the first frames of a
> video are being played, I'd suggest wrapping this in a
> [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout) or listening to the [`timeupdate`](https://github.com/vimeo/player.js#timeupdate) event.